# Setting up Apache HttpComponents PoolingClientConnectionManager for Spring Web RestTemplate

Tags: spring

I am using `RestClient` to connect to a remote JSON API.
Previously, in Spring 3.0, I was using Commons HTTPClient.
I found that performance was low due to a lot of locking in the old multithreaded connection manager.

I now want to try Apache HttpComponents 4.2 since it appears they fixed up the locking.
I would like to use the `PoolingClientConnectionManager` as the constructor parameter for the `DefaultHttpClient` that will be autowired for the different classes.

The challenge is setting up the `PoolingClientConnectionManager` connection manager. I want a high number of concurrent connection to the JSON API provider. These use `HttpRoute` objects to represent the hostname. But, as described in http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingClientConnectionManager.html, `PoolingClientConnectionManager` uses a `setMaxPerRoute(HttpRoute, int maxConnections)` method.

How can I set up the connection manager a Spring context.xml file, since it doesn't use simple setters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about wrapping the PoolingClientConnectionManager by extending it, and then creating setters using a Bean representing a route/max value. Ie.

```
// Your bean
public class RouteMax() {
  private HttpRoute httpRoute;
  private int max;
  ... setters/getters
}

// Extending the PoolingClientConnectionManager
...
public class CustomPoolingClientConnectionManager extends PoolingClientConnectionManager {
...
public setRouteMax(RouteMax routeMax) {
  super.setMaxPerRoute(routeMax.getHttpRoute(), routeMax.getMax());
}
```

..then in your Spring config you can set the routeMax property using your RouteMax bean.

Answer (score 1):

In your Spring context.xml file, a better way to configure your httpClient with the PoolingClientConnectionManager is:

```
<bean id="httpClient" class="org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient">
<constructor-arg>
<bean class="org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager">
<property name="maxTotal" value="100" />
<property name="defaultMaxPerRoute" value="50" />
</bean>
</constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

The maxTotal and defaultMaxPerRoute properties should be configured according to the manual:

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d5e627